# Powershell how to add headers to a out-filed csv

Tags: powershell, csv, header

Do some of you know how to add headers to an out-file csv?
I was looking on many other examples but don't find one that can help me.

Right now my output looks like this:

```
Name : Steve 
Adress: Berlin
Age: 21
And more....
```

but I would like to get it like this

```
Name  Adress   Age
----  -------  ---
Steve Berlin   21
```

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Config.xml'
[xml]$blacklist = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\EVIM.Script\EVIM-Blacklist.xml'



#Names to filter
$BLN = $blacklist.Names
#Import Path
$info = Import-Csv $config.config.path.input -Delimiter ';'
$info | Format-Table
#from which month
#$dateCutoff = get-date "02.2020" -Format "MM.yyyy"
$dateCutoff = $config.config.date
$result = foreach($i in $info){
    if(-Not($BLN -contains $i.SCAN_USER)){


        $entryDate = Get-Date $i.SCAN_DATE -Format "MM.yyyy"


        if($entryDate -eq $dateCutoff){
        $i
        }
     }
   $result | Out-File $config.config.path.output 
   Write-Host $i
   $config.config.path.output + "\" + $info | Out-File -Append $config.config.path.output 
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `$result | format-table | out-file $config.config.path.output`? Of course that will not be usable in any realistic way if reading that output file for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Export-CSV:**

To export CSV documents you shouldn't use `Out-File`. You should use `Export-CSV`:

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path ".\yourdocumentname.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
```

---

**Using Out-File:**

```
$data | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation | Out-File ".\yourdocumentname.csv" -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: Okay, weird But can you please test it?

Comment: The german comments apprently got deleted, so here in english:
I edited the code again. Can you try it again?

Comment: i tried but now its all like pushed together (so its not in a table)

Comment: Did you open it with excel? CSV aren't meant to be a table. If you want to be able to have a nice table inside excel use Delimiter ';'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209564/discussion-between-nicicalu-and-dustin-zimmermann).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can't achieve luck using Import-Csv or Export-Csv if you are restricted to use out-file :(

What you have to do is you have to pass a pscustomobject to the output Csv file.

Give a try to this:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
  Name = "Anything, you can use variables in place of this string"
  Address = "String or variable"
  Age = Integer or Variable
} | out-file "filepath.csv"
```

Next when you want to get its content use get-content rather than import-Csv

```
Get-Content "filepath.csv"
```

If you are exporting hash tables to text file then first convert it to pscustomobject:

```
   $object = New-Object PSObject
   $hashtable.GetEnumerator() |  ForEach { Add-Member -inputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -name $_.Name -value $_.Value }
  $object | out-file "filepath.csv"
```

FYI I have run test on [TIO](https://tio.run/#powershell%20) and my PC.

Comment: He could use ConvertTo-Csv and then Out-File

Comment: is there an easy way what i can do when i always get the message that i dont have the permission to use this path xD